# Insert continuous data flow into a database

Tags: mysql, json, neo4j, sqlite

My question is quite generic and about architectural doing.

I receive a lot of data continously (JSON). This could be up to 30 jsons a seconde.

I need to insert each into a database, with many different queries to dispatch information. This database could be anything but i prefer Neo4j.

If saw that if i insert as soon as i receive, then the inserts go more and more late, i mean i got 500 json files and 200 are inserted (even with indexes in db).

So i think i should separate the job : one script to receive data, and one script or separate thread to insert into the database.

So, according to your experience, what could be the best way for this case ? temporay json files on the disk waiting to be processed ?

Answer (score 0):

As almost always in such a generic case, the answer is **it depends**. It depends for example on how big each incoming update is (and how much processing is required to apply it). It also depends on whether or not the updates are independent (does the order of updates matter ?). What you could for example do is collect incoming updates in a queue/inbox and then have multiple threads asynchronously pick up the updates and execute them in parallel.

I'd say that more information on your actual use-case is needed to give a more detailed solution.

Hope this helps, Tom

Comment: The order doesent matter. This is "insert or replace" for same type of objects. Queries are always the same.

Comment: If the order doesn't matter I would definitely "fan out" the input over multiple asynchronous threads to do parallel updates (although you will have to look into locking issues). Something like Apache Kafka (just an example, I'm not voicing a preference) between your input and Neo4j in the backend.